# Coloring the faces of a regular tetrahedron with 3 colors using Burnside's lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, rotations, symmetry, coloring

I have to determine the number of ways the faces of a regular tetrahedron can be colored with three colors. I already know it is 15, but apparently the math professor did not find the solution to his liking. I need to use group theory and Burnside's lemma to explain how you determine the number of ways the faces of regular tetrahedron can colored with three colors. What I understand: the basics of abstract algebra/group theory, but not much about how to apply group theory to solve this specific problem.

Comment: Do you have to use all three of the available colors, or do you include colorings where only one or two of the colors is used?

Comment: @bof It seems that only rotations are allowed and not all the colours have to be used.

Comment: This [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413032/) here uses PET but you should be able to derive Burnside from it since the terms in the cycle index also let you calculate the number of colorings fixed by a permutation having that factorization into disjoint cycles. Use inclusion-exclusion for exactly three colors as opposed to at most three colors.